# Adding Fragment to BackStack using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which is used as the ViewPagerAdapter for my ActionBar etc. I am trying to change a fragment and add the previous one to the backstack. It appears, however, that this is not possible.

If I look at the [Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-mr1-dev/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java) it seems as though the only way around this is to destroy the old Fragment then add the new one. This is not optimal for what I am trying to do (multipage form). What I really want to do is take the existing fragment and detach it, then add a new fragment and add it to the backstack.

I have tried this without the ViewPager and it works flawlessly. Short of rewriting my own FragmentStatePagerAdapter class that allows me to replace items in the Fragments List is there anything else I can do?

Comment: *Short of rewriting my own FragmentStatePagerAdapter class that allows me to replace items in the Fragments List is there anything else I can do?* - implement nested fragments.

Comment: +Luksprog do you have an example of doing this, not too familiar with it.